# What to do with continuously growing redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an React-Redux application where in on users navigation around the application, store data grows. Now I want to know since store has large chunk of data, is this a case of memory leak? I mean is that clearing unwanted data will reduce the memory usage?
Why I am asking is that I know redux keep the older state as well to track the history so I am confused that even if removal of data from store is going to help?

Comment: Please have a look at https://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#performance-state-memory